# How can I write one method that accepts either Graphics or XGraphics as argument?

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I have code that uses `Graphics` class to draw string on a PNG image, and very similar code to generate PDF (using PdfSharp)

```cs
void DrawText(Graphics gfx, string text) // used to draw PNG images
{
    // assume that someFont and someBrush, x, y has already been defined
    gfx.DrawString(text, someFont, someBrush, x, y);
}


void DrawText(XGraphics gfx, string text)  // used for PDF generation
{
    gfx.DrawString(text, someFont, someBrush, x, y);
}
```

There are few differences between `Graphics` and `XGraphics` but they share a lot of method names and structure.

How can I re-write my code to remove the duplicate function and take advantage of both classes using methods with the same signature?

I attempted to create an interface like so:

```cs
public interface IGraphics
{
    void DrawString(string text, Font font, Brush brush, float x, float y);
}
```

and then I re-wrote my code to draw string:

```cs
void DrawText(IGraphics gfx, string text) // used to draw PNG images
{
    gfx.DrawString(text, someFont, someBrush, x, y);
}
```

but whenever I try to call `DrawText()` using either a `Graphics` or `XGraphics` instance, I get an error that these types cannot be converted from their type to `IGraphics`.

Is there a different way to re-use `DrawText()` by `Graphics` and `XGraphics`?

Comment: C# has a nominal type system. Unless `XGraphics` and `Graphics` are defined as implementing an interface, they are not subtypes of it even if they have identical members. One option would be to use a delegate: `void DrawText(Action<string, Font, Brush, float, float> draw, string text) => draw(text, someFont, someBrush, x, y)` and call it like `DrawString(gfx.DrawString, text)`;